# asp.net mvc gridmvc datepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I am a beginner to the mvc concept, I am trying to implement a datepicker in my mvc project, which steps are still missing ?

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10 date-picker">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "date-picker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have used Nuget to install gridmvc datepicker. I have also put in the _layout.cshtml :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // This will make every element with the class "date-picker" into a DatePicker element
        $('.date-picker').datepicker();
    })
</script>
```

until now - I get only textbox and not calender

Comment: Sanity check - you do have jQuery on the page, right?

Comment: I have in the _layout.cshtml:    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>